# Storing and updating symmetrical many-to-many relationships between observations in R

Tags: r, database, sqlite, dataframe, relationship

I've got a Shiny app I'm using to view and manage some data with lots of related observations. Because of a technical limitation at the original source each observation is initially only tied to one other observation, with larger groups made by chaining things together (A related to B, B related to C, C related to B).

Here's a simplified example, minus the Shiny GUI:

```
#How the data comes from the original source
original_data<-tribble(
  ~observation,         ~related_to,
    "A",                     "B",
    "B",                     "C",
    "C",                     "E",
    "D",                     NA,
    "E",                     "D"
)


#After I go through by hand and tally up related cases
my_handtyped_data<-tribble(
  ~observation,       ~related_to,
  "A",                "B,C,D,E",
  "B",                "A,C,D,E",
  "C",                "A,B,D,E",
  "D",                "A,B,C,E",
  "E",                "A,B,C,D"
```

My current method is going through by hand and just typing out related cases as a string. What I want to find is a way to programmatically clean up transitive A-to-B-to-C situations as well as keep all relation data up to date when new rows of data are entered or existing relations are updated.

I've come up with a potential data.table and dplyr approach for propagating changes to related cases that will work on the same or separate table, but I want to be sure there there isn't a package or function already more suited to this. Or that this isn't more SQLite's territory, which is available since I already use a local SQLite file for persistent storage.

```
#in actual use these three will be taken from shiny session values
selected_row<-2
selected_observation<-my_handtyped_data$observation[[selected_row]]
related_list<-list("replace", "with", "something")

#data.table approach
my_handtyped_data[observation %in% related_list, related_to := c(related_list, selected_observation)]
my_handtyped_data[selected_row, related_to:=related_list]

#dplyr approach, anti_join->bind_rows might be written wrong
my_handtyped_data %<>%
  filter(observation %in% c(related_list,selected_observation))
  mutate(
    related_to=
     if_else(
      observation==selected_observation,
      related_list,
      c(related_list,selected_observation)
      ) %>%
  anti_join(related_cases_table,.)%>%
  bind_rows(.,related_cases_table)
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I altered your data a bit (introducing node 'Q', so we get two groups nof nodes...)

Using the `igraph` [ackage, you can easily get groups of nodes that are related to eachother..

```
**sample data**
original_data<-tribble(
  ~observation,         ~related_to,
  "A",                     "Q",       #  <-- !! 
  "B",                     "C",
  "C",                     "E",
  "D",                     NA,
  "E",                     "D"
)

library( tibble )
library( igraph )

#get df of nodes
nodes <- tibble( name = unique( na.omit( stack( original_data )$values ) ) ) 
#create list of edges
edges <- original_data[ complete.cases( original_data ), ]
#build igraph
g <- graph_from_data_frame(d = edges, vertices = nodes, directed = FALSE)
```

looks like this

[image]

and the groups are...

```
#get groups of nodes
groups(components(g) )

# $`1`
# [1] "A" "Q"
# 
# $`2`
# [1] "B" "C" "D" "E"
```

Comment: And that would be why I asked, this completely moots the need to do pretty much anything extra. I'd run into graph databases researching this but for some reason igraph never showed up when I tried to find R packages. Ever since google "improved" their algorithm...